# Only transpose data to a new column if it is a new group of data / excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of data in excel which could potentially have data over 2000 rows. In that data there is groups of data that I would like to send to the top of a new column every time a new group is found. I've looked at the special paste option for transpose along with using a delimiter but i can only move data one column over and not to the top. I'm looking for a solution which is fast due to the amount of data that would need to be split into new columns. I appreciate the help.

Below is a table of how the data looks.

[image]

Below is how I would like the data to look

[image]

Comment: Definetly sounds like a job for some VBA. However we are not going to write that for you from scratch. Show us the effort and research you put into it, and we'll help you go the last mile so to say.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple code,

```
Sub splitRange()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Cells(1, 6) = Cells(1, 1)
Cells(1, 7) = Cells(1, 2)
j = 1
k = 6
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
        j = j + 1
        Cells(j, k) = Cells(i, 1)
        Cells(j, k + 1) = Cells(i, 2)
    Else
        k = k + 3
        j = 1
        Cells(j, k) = Cells(i, 1)
        Cells(j, k + 1) = Cells(i, 2)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Modify the code if you want the output in a separate sheet. I would like you to google it to learn about it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar.  You can try also this code:

```
Sub Move_Data()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim r  As Integer
    Dim StartRow As Integer
    Dim EndRow As Integer
    Dim ColA As Integer
    Dim vLastRow As Integer
    Dim vEnd As Integer

    r = 1
    StartRow = 1
    EndRow = 1
    ColA = 4
    vEnd = 1

    vLastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

    Do Until Cells(r, 1) <> Cells(StartRow, 1)
        DoEvents
        r = r + 1
    Loop

    vEnd = r

    Do Until r > vLastRow

        DoEvents

        StartRow = r

        Do Until Cells(r, 1) <> Cells(StartRow, 1)
            DoEvents
            r = r + 1
        Loop

        EndRow = r - 1

        Range(Cells(StartRow, 1), Cells(EndRow, 2)).Select

        Selection.Copy

        Cells(1, ColA).Select

        ActiveSheet.Paste

        ColA = ColA + 3

    Loop

    r = vEnd + 1

    Range(Cells(vEnd, 1), Cells(vLastRow, 2)).ClearContents

    Cells(1, 1).Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```